# how can I fix this result with java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a line like this :

```
EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=50,EPRE=ENABLED,T200=44-31-41-90-90-90-135
```

with java Regex ,I want to show this :

```
EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=50,EPRE=ENABLED
```

I wrote this as Regex :

```
^EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=[^,]*,EPRE=ENABLED$
```

but it's not show me correctly , why? thanks

Thanks for your help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` at the end means it will only match the end of the string. You just want to stop the match at the end, not require that it *is* the end of the input. Try just:

```
^EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=[^,]*,EPRE=ENABLED
```

Sample code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String text = "EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=50,EPRE=ENABLED,T200=44-31-41-90-90-90-135";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=[^,]*,EPRE=ENABLED");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        if (matcher.lookingAt())
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try with this : System.out.println(result.split("^EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=[^,]*,EPRE=ENABLED")[0]); but it's not show me agian !

Comment: @MikeRedford: You're not really trying to *split* it on that though are you? See my edit for sample code.

Comment: @MikeRedford: Why would you want to? `split` is meant for *separator* - and this certainly doesn't look like a separator. Additionally, the point of split is *not* to return the separators, but the things between them. If you could give us more information about what you're trying to do rather than the way you were hoping to achieve it, that would help.

Comment: Actually my file has 3000 line, could you please tell me how can I find this line "EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=50,EPRE=ENABLED,T200=44-31-41-90-90-90-135
" very fast ?

Comment: @MikeRedford: You iterate through each line, matching the regex against each line.